# How to use Apple watch PushNotificationPayload.apns

Tags: apple-watch

I'm trying to understand the usage of PushNotificationPayload.apns
From what I understand, I can only specify this file if running through the simulator. If that's the case, how am I supposed to receive remote notifications? Since when does the simulator support remote notifications? And even if it does, how do I get the device token from it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PushNotificationPayload.apns` is indeed usable in the simulator only. It is actually useful *because* the Simulator does not support push notification.

It is simply a file containing a Push Notification payload that can be used to simulate receiving a push notification on the Simulator.

You can tell the simulator this payload should be used in your tests by editing your WatchKit App scheme, setting the Watch Interface to Dynamic or Static Notification. Then you’ll be able to specify which payload to use for the notification view.

Comment: how do I actually cause the simulator to handle the file and handle it as if it just received a remote notification ?

Comment: Just run your WatchKit App scheme after configuring it as said in my answer.